# How to pass the variable from one component to another

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**I know the question looks redundant, I've a different problem and I am not able to find it here.**

I want a function to return an Id and that Id must me passed on to the another component

***If you want the full code it is here*** https://codesandbox.io/s/qz7n1yy06j

mainpage.js

```
onEditClick(objectId){
        return <EditRow objectId={objectId}/>
    }
```

FYI I tried Console in the mainpage, it has the correct value, but when it is passed on to editrow, it becomes undefined.

editrow.js

```
   class EditRow extends React.Component{

    renderTextField(field){
        return(
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>{field.label}</label>
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={field.placeholder}
                    {...field.input}
                    required
                />
            </div>
        )
    }

    onSubmit(values){
        this.props.editRow(values, () => {
            this.props.history.push('/login_success');
        },this.props.objectId);
    }

    render(){
        const {handleSubmit}=this.props;

        return(
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <Field
                    label={"Student Name"}
                    placeholder={"Enter the Name"}
                    name="name"
                    component={this.renderTextField}
                />
                <Field
                    label={"Average Grade"}
                    placeholder={"Enter the Average grade"}
                    name="avgGrade"
                    component={this.renderTextField}
                />
                <Field
                    label={"Curriculum / Occupation"}
                    placeholder={"Enter the Curriculum or Occupation"}
                    name="occupation"
                    component={this.renderTextField}
                />
                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-right">Edit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({form:'EditRow'})(connect (null,{editRow})(EditRow));
```

I'm trying to pass the value to the component when the form gets submitted. I surfed about this and got none. Real help would be nice.
So please before giving minus points, give me the answer. Thank you

Comment: what are you doing with the react element returned from `onEditClick`?

Comment: what is `editRow` function doing? It is taken from props passed to `EditRow` but I don't see that prop passed in your first code snippet.

Comment: There's a lot more going on in your code that you showed here. It's hard to tell what's going on without knowing the rest.

Comment: Yeah I did @ThilinaSampath

Comment: try log `objectId` in **mainpage.js**

Comment: Can't understand, are you telling me you console log it?

Comment: I would help if you could create a simplified version of what you want to do without all the clutter of other irrelevant code to this problem.

Comment: Sorry for me being stupid.. If you want the whole code I could send it to you

Comment: Can you put the whole code in codesandbox

Comment: Yes, I will put it and update you

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/qz7n1yy06j @Harikrishnan I've put it in the codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `react-route` for routing to edit page on clicking of edit button you don't need to return the `editrow` component as the rendering of new component is taken care by the `react-router` `Link`,so you need to pass the objectId as params as

```
 <Link to={"/login_success/editdetails/" + this.props.row.objectId}>
        <button className="edit">
              Edit
        </button>    
 </Link>
```

In the route you need to mention the params as

```
 <Route path="/login_success/editdetails/:objectId" component={EditRow} />
```

Then you can access the params in `editrow` component as

```
this.props.match.params.objectId
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor for the component class and call super with props, that is.

Also try to bind the onSubmit method to the class.

```
class EditRow extends React.Component{

   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
   }

   renderTextField(field){

   //.... rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is convoluted so I try to give you the answer (and an example) on how to pass props between components.

The most straight-forward way is to put data in the closest common ancestor.

```js
class App extends React.Component { // app is the closest common ancestor
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      data: ""  // here we store the data both components will use
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => { // this function is passed to one component to fetch data from it
    const data = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(() => ({data}));
  }

  render() {
    const {data} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Comp1 onChange={this.onChange}/> { /* this component is providing the data */ }
        <Display value={data} />  { /* this component is using the data */ }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Comp1 = ({onChange}) => {
  return <input onChange={onChange} />;
}

const Display = ({value}) => {
  return <p>{value}</p>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g65mbj

One thing to note is that the data is stored in state which causes the both components to rerender with new information. If it didn't rerender, the data would be changed but the view would be still the same as before changes.

Other ways to share data between components are:

- context
- state management systems like redux or mobx